# Is there a way to call scala lamda function from the pyspark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, py4j

I have a lambda function define in scala.

```scala
package com.stack.flow.info

object ObjForExp{

val getColumn: String => Column = (columnName) =>  {
    col(columnName)
  }

def cool(t:String):Unit={
    print(t)
}

}
```

I want to call it using pyspark.

I know I can pass the jar as.

```sh
pyspark --jars sample.jar
```

Also, I know I can call method `cool` as.

```py
sc._jvm.com.stack.flow.info.ObjForExp.cool("What Ever")
```

But is there is a way to call scala lambda function to pyspark for e.g. `getColumn` ?

What I know is that py4j acts as an actual spark java code so there is a chance that py4j doesn't have any idea how to handle.

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.UDFRegistration.registerJavaFunction

Comment: I am not looking for UDFs.

Comment: but what you're describing is essentially a scala UDF

Comment: It will be a UDF when I wrap it under UDF as a next step. This is not a UDF.

Comment: That's why I suggested the link to the docs about creating UDFs